# How to mock PostgresSQL database with pytest fixture

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, pytest

I have a file with two functions that I must test that look like this:

```
def create_conn(config):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname = config['dbname'], ...)
    return conn

def use_conn():
    conn = create_conn(CONSTANT_CONFIG)
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("some sql query")
    conn.close()
```

I've been able to create `pytest` fixtures for testing functions that use DynamoDB and S3 with a mock database using `moto` that essentially overrides any call to `boto3` like below:

```
# in conftest.py
@pytest.fixture()
def s3_client(aws_credentials):
    with moto.mock_s3()
        client = boto3.client('s3')
        yield client

# in test file
def test_func(s3_client):
     func() # a function that uses boto3
```

But I can't come across any examples that do something similar for PostgresSQL databases. Is there anyway to essentially override `psycopg2.connect()` to return a connection to a mock database? I think `pytest-postgresql` might help, but I couldn't find any code examples.

Comment: What is your end goal really? If you want to test connecting to the database, making the query and checking you get the right results out, then why not spin up Postgres in Docker and run the tests against that? Are you worried about speed of the tests here?

Comment: The solution I went with to solve this was to spin up a local docker container that had Postgres running. Doing this removed the complexity of having to care about mocking out the connection component. Here is an example fixture that I'm using in my code: https://gist.github.com/idjaw/d3df6685f7943d5807ebd479fb383171. Disclaimer, there is a refactor that needs to be done to improve how well it resets between test runs. But, this should give you an idea of what is done. For pytest-postgres, [documentation](https://github.com/ClearcodeHQ/pytest-postgresql) explains things fairly well.